# Biber remove certain fields from citation

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

How can I remove certain fields from the citation in Biber?

My example document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,firstinits=true,citestyle=ieee]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{example_library.bib}

\begin{document}

Dummy text \cite{Zaharia2012}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

With an example library `example_library.bib` of:

```
@article{Zaharia2012,
abstract = {We present Resilient Distributed Datasets (RDDs), a distributed memory abstraction that lets programmers perform in-memory computations on large clusters in a fault-tolerant manner. RDDs are motivated by two types of applications that current computing frameworks handle inefficiently: iterative algorithms and interactive data mining tools. In both cases, keeping data in memory can improve performance by an order of magnitude. To achieve fault tolerance efficiently, RDDs provide a restricted form of shared memory, based on coarse-grained transformations rather than fine-grained updates to shared state. However, we show that RDDs are expressive enough to capture a wide class of computations, including recent specialized programming models for iterative jobs, such as Pregel, and new applications that these models do not capture. We have implemented RDDs in a system called Spark, which we evaluate through a variety of user applications and benchmarks.},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
arxivId = {EECS-2011-82},
author = {Zaharia, Matei and Chowdhury, Mosharaf and Das, Tathagata and Dave, Ankur},
doi = {10.1111/j.1095-8649.2005.00662.x},
eprint = {EECS-2011-82},
isbn = {978-931971-92-8},
issn = {00221112},
journal = {NSDI'12 Proceedings of the 9th USENIX conference on Networked Systems Design and Implementation},
pmid = {2011},
title = {{Resilient distributed datasets: A fault-tolerant abstraction for in-memory cluster computing}},
year = {2012}
}
```

renders as:
[image]

How can I reduce the fields and only get an Output similarly to:

```
[1] M. Zaharia, M. Chowdhury, T. Das, et al. "Resilient distributed datasets: A fault-tolerant abstraction for in-memory cluster computing". In: NSDI'12 Proceedings of the 9th USENIX conference on Networked Systems Design and Implementation (2012).
```

Even when adding:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey, match=\regexp{\Actan\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldset=url, null]
      \step[fieldset=arxivId, null]
      \step[fieldset=archivePrefix, null]
    }
  }
}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{archivePrefix}\clearlist{issn}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{archivePrefix, arxivId, issn}} 
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{url}} 
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{issn}}
```

these additional fields are not cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the first `\step` the sourcemap shown in the question only applies to entries with the entry key `ctan`. Since the key of the example entry is `Zaharia2012`, the mapping does not apply.

The shown `\clearlist` and `\clearfield` statements wouldn't work for a variety of reasons. `archivePrefix` is a convenience/legacy alias for the proper field `eprinttype`, so only `\clearfield{eprinttype}` would work. `issn` and `url` are *fields* not *lists*, so they would need to be cleared with `\clearfield`. `\clearlist{archivePrefix, arxivId, issn}` doesn't work because `\clearlist` accepts only one list name and not a whole list of them.

Since you are already using sourcemaps I suggest you clear all fields with a sourcemap.

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, giveninits=true, citestyle=ieee]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=doi, null]
      \step[fieldset=url, null]
      \step[fieldset=eprint, null]
      \step[fieldset=eprinttype, null]
      \step[fieldset=arxivId, null]
      \step[fieldset=archivePrefix, null]
      \step[fieldset=issn, null]
      \step[fieldset=isbn, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Zaharia2012,
  archivePrefix = {arXiv},
  arxivId       = {EECS-2011-82},
  author        = {Zaharia, Matei and Chowdhury, Mosharaf
                   and Das, Tathagata and Dave, Ankur},
  doi           = {10.1111/j.1095-8649.2005.00662.x},
  eprint        = {EECS-2011-82},
  isbn          = {978-931971-92-8},
  issn          = {00221112},
  journal       = {NSDI'12 Proceedings of the 9th USENIX conference
                   on Networked Systems Design and Implementation},
  pmid          = {2011},
  title         = {Resilient distributed datasets},
  subtitle      = {A fault-tolerant abstraction for in-memory cluster computing},
  year          = {2012}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Dummy text \cite{Zaharia2012}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I didn't change this in the example, but from what I can see it looks as if the entry should be an `@inproceedings` and not an `@article`.

---

In this particular case where you want to get rid of URLs, DOIs, eprints and ISSN/ISBN you could also use the style options `url=false, doi=false, eprint=false, isbn=false,`. So it would be enough to load `biblatex` as

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=ieee, giveninits=true, 
  url=false, doi=false, eprint=false, isbn=false,]{biblatex}
```

But those options are only available for those few fields and not for more.

Comment: It is still rendering the full bib resource including DOI and other deleted fields for me using PDF latex.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Indeed. That should be proceedings.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler Oh yeah, I forgot the DOI. Sorry. Please try again.

Comment: I still see https://imgur.com/a/3V9hKZk the full thing - not reduced by any of the fields which are nulled out.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler Did you run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX after you added the new code? Did you try the code in a new file in an empty folder?

Comment: Ineed clearing these caches helped.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler Clearing files should usually not be necessary, but it is necessary to run a full LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX cycle after changes to sourcemaps. That is because the sourcemap is executed on the Biber side. The first LaTeX run writes the sourcemap definition to a helper file (the `.bcf` file). Biber then reads this helper file, executes the sourcemap and writes the bibliography data in LaTeX-readable format to the `.bbl` file. In the second LaTeX run the data is read from the `.bbl` and used. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864.